# Move vaule into register from array

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

I try to learn assembler and wrote a simple program, that defines an arr, with
three equal values, and i want to copy the second vaule in to reister *eax*.
The code works and compile for the first value when i use the statement `mov eax, [arr]` it gives the result **Ah** in the register. But when i try to copy the second value of the array in to the register *eax* it does not work:
`mov eax, [arr+1]`, it gives the value **0A000000h**.
The function `DumpRegs` just shows the register values in the command promt, i dont have the source code for that. (But its from a good source, from a books website).

code:

```
ExitProcess PROTO,dwExitCode:DWORD
DumpRegs PROTO
.data
    arr DWORD 10,10,10
.code
main PROC
    mov eax, [arr+1];
    call    DumpRegs
    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

Its written in masm in visual studio.

Comment: OK i think i found out the error i need to add 4.

Answer (score 0):

eax is 32 bit, so i have to move the pointer 4 bytes to next element `mov eax, [arr+4]`